# Cannot set MS Word as default XML handler in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, xml

I store my Word documents in XML format to allow version handling.  If I set the default file handler for the .xml file extension to Notepad++, Chrome, Excel, or any other program, then Windows attempts to open the XML file in the specified program.  If I set the default app to Word, however, then the file opens in Notepad.

I made some small progress here by changing the registry key `PercievedType` from `text` to `document` at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xml`: now Windows opens a dialogue box asking "How do you want to open this file", with Word listed as the default.

I know this is a minor annoyance, but I'd really appreciate any suggestions..

As requested in the comments, here are links to screenshots showing that when I use the [right-click menu](http://community.dur.ac.uk/martin.smith/img/XML_2.png) to select the default file handler, [Microsoft Word is selected](http://community.dur.ac.uk/martin.smith/img/XML_1.png), though I the associated tickbox is unchecked until I click it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the registry tweaks you've did and right-click on a .XML file and hover in open with and click "chose another app" and click on word and don't forget to click the button always open with.

Comment: Please Comment back of this answer is not working,

Comment: This just opens up the "How do you want to open this file" dialog, in which Word is already selected as the default option.  Clicking "Always use this app to open .xml files" has no effect.

Comment: Please remove all the registry tweaks you have done

Comment: I've reverted the `PercievedType` back to `document` and now XML files once again open with Notepad, even though Word is set as the default file handler (by following your instruction).

Comment: Can you attach some screenshots please

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a missing registry entry in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.xml`.  Adding the entry `PerceivedType = text` fixed the problem.

A corresponding entry did exist in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`: I wonder whether Windows 10 is more actively deprecating this registry branch, which [seems to be](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl) a hangover from Windows 3.1.